# Unable to use Mockito in a maven project in intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, mockito

Here is my pom file https://ibb.co/fp3kVv

And here is what happanes if i try to initiate it in a test class https://ibb.co/nKkhAv

`JUnit` seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your pom file looks correct. Can you try "mvn clean install -U" ? Also, if that doesn't work. You can try reading this :

[Mockito test not seen by Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122283/mockito-test-not-seen-by-maven)

Comment: heh i am still new to the more "advanced" stuff in intellij where do i type that "mvn clean install -U"? And btw yesterday i downloaded mockito to use on a project in a completly different directory and it worked there. Idk if that helps you or not.

Comment: Try typing that command in terminal within intellij :) or just terminal in your directory.

Comment: https://ibb.co/cL5oiF i hope this is what you told me to do and i didin't misuderstood and see the message "'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,"

Comment: Refer to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19090928/mvn-command-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: I am not a windows expert but it seems like your maven wasn't installed properly :)

Comment: ye i guess so i haven't rly installed it, but intellij just has it as option on creating projects and it seems to work 1 time and 5 it doesn't i am just going to watch some tutorials on how to properly install it my self

Comment: Sorry, i couldn't help :(